# Comparing $\text{tr}(A^{-1})$ and $\text{tr}(A(B+A)^{-2})$ for pd $A$ and psd $B$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Suppose that $A$ is positive definite and $B$ positive semidefinite, both with dimension $n\times n$. Is there some inequality between
$$
\text{tr}(A^{-1})\quad\text{and}\quad\text{tr}(A(B+A)^{-2})?
$$
**Progress so far**: When $n=1$ with $A=a>0$, $B=b\geq 0$, we have
$$
\text{tr}(A(B+A)^{-2})=\frac{a}{(a+b)^2}\leq\frac{a}{a^2}=\frac{1}{a}=\text{tr}(A^{-1}).
$$
So it is suggestive that $\text{tr}(A(B+A)^{-2})\leq \text{tr}(A^{-1})$. I have tried
\begin{align*}
\text{tr}(A(B+A)^{-2})&=\text{tr}[A[B+A]^{-1}[B+A]^{-1}]\\
&=\text{tr}[A[A^{1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}+I)A^{1/2}]^{-1}[A^{1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}+I)A^{1/2}]^{-1}]\\
&=\text{tr}[AA^{-1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}+I)^{-1}A^{-1}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}+I)^{-1}A^{-1/2}]\\
&=\text{tr}[A^{-1}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}+I)^{-2}]\\
&\leq\text{tr}[A^{-1}]\text{tr}[(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}+I)^{-2}].
\end{align*}
If $e_1,\ldots,e_n\geq 0$ are the eigenvalues of $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$, then
$$
\text{tr}[(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}+I)^{-2}]=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(e_i+1)^2}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(0+1)^2}=n.
$$
Thus, we have proved
$$
\text{tr}(A(B+A)^{-2})\leq n\text{tr}[A^{-1}].
$$
But this isn't really what we seek. Plus, when $B$ is the zero matrix, $\text{tr}(A(B+A)^{-2})=\text{tr}[A^{-1}]$ so it seems the inequality can be made tigher.

Comment: If your pd and psd imply symmetricity here, why not prove that $A^{-1}-A(B+A)^{-2}$ is psd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric. We have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}\left(A(B+A)^{-2}\right)
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((B+A)^{-1}A(B+A)^{-1}\right)\\
&\le\operatorname{tr}\left((B+A)^{-1}(B+A)(B+A)^{-1}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((B+A)^{-1}\right)\\
&\le\operatorname{tr}\left(A^{-1}\right).
\end{align}